# Python: trying to lower a string and remove non-alphanumeric characters aside from space

Tags: python

I'm trying to remove all non-alphanumeric characters except the space from a string, but can't seem to figure out how I exclude space. I'm currently doing it this way:

```
re.sub('[\W_]+', '', text).lower().strip()
```

But running my function yields the following results:

```
print removePunctuation('Hi, you!')
print removePunctuation(' No under_score!')
hiyou
nounderscore
```

Where I want it to be:

```
hi you
no underscore
```

So how do I exclude space from being replaced?

My current optimum is this:

```
re.sub('[^\s\w]+', '', text).lower().strip().replace('_','')
```

Comment: Do you also want to remove leading and trailing spaces?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use this,

```
re.sub(r'[^\sa-zA-Z0-9]', '', text).lower().strip()
```

**Example:**

```
>>> import re
>>> def removePunctuation(s):
        return re.sub(r'[^\sa-zA-Z0-9]', '', s).lower().strip()

>>> print removePunctuation('Hi, you!')
hi you
>>> print removePunctuation(' No under_score!')
no underscore
```

**OR**

```
re.sub('(?!\s)[\W_]', '', text).lower().strip()
```

Comment: except the underscore will still be there

Comment: thanks! will accept it unless something closer to my solution appears.

Answer (score 0):

You might like a list comprehension better here:

```
result = ''.join([c for c in myString if str.isalnum(c) or str.isspace(c)])
```

Comment: Using `''.join(c for c in myString if str.isalnum(c) or str.isspace(c))` will save memory.

Comment: @EliKorvigo, no it won't as a list is built first if you pass a generator expression to join

Comment: @PadraicCunningham that is a nice thing to know, thank you. Btw, how did you find it out? I've looked for the `join` method sources and they show nothing.

Comment: @EliKorvigo, join does two passes over the data so it has to create a list first if you pass it a generator or after the first pass it would be consumed

Answer (score 0):

How about a generator comprehension? It's much more readable than using RegExp.

```
def removePunctuation(s):
    return ''.join(l for l in s if l.isalnum() or l == ' ').lower().strip()
```

Or as a `lambda`

```
removePunctuation = lambda s: ''.join(l for l in s if l.isalnum() or l == ' ').lower().strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove punctuation with str.translate:

```
s = 'Hi, you!'

from string import  punctuation

print(s.translate(None,punctuation).lower())
hi you
```

For python3:

```
s = 'Hi, you!'

from string import  punctuation

print(s.translate({ord(k):"" for k in punctuation}).lower())
hi you
```

In a function:

```
from string import punctuation

def remove_punctuation(s):
    return s.translate(None,punctuation).lower()

def remove_punctuation(s):
    return s.translate({ord(k): "" for k in punctuation}).lower()
```

Output:

```
In [3]: remove_punctuation(' No under_score!')
Out[3]: ' no underscore'

In [4]: remove_punctuation('Hi, you!')
Out[4]: 'hi you'
```

If you want to remove leading spaces add strip.

```
from string import punctuation
def remove_punctuation(s):
    return s.translate(None,punctuation).lower().strip()
```

Output:

```
In [6]: remove_punctuation(' No under_score!')
Out[6]: 'no underscore'

In [7]: remove_punctuation('Hi, you!')
Out[7]: 'hi you'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can approach the problem from the otherside:

```
re.sub('([^\w ]|_)+', '', 'a ,_  b').lower().strip()
```

It gives `a   b`

So you're saying: Remove everything that is not an alphanumeric character and not a space or is an underscore character.

Comment: Except '_' will still be included

Comment: '_' also needs to be removed